# Getting error when trying to install PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, json

I am trying to install PHP on Ubuntu 14.04 on EC2 instance of AWS using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php php-json
```

But I am getting an error saying:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package php
>
> E: Unable to locate package php-json

I have tried installing it after this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apache2
```

So how to resolve this?

Comment: This is more of a SuperUser question, but you can find the exact package name by doing `sudo apt-cache search json | grep php` to find the exact package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo aptitude install php5-json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this guide if you are trying to installing LAMP: https://www.truespotmedia.com/install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-ubuntu-16/

You can install the JSON extension using PEAR:

```
pecl install json
```

If you are trying to enable the enable the JSON extension for PHP:

1. Open the file `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`
2. This add this: `extension=json.so` to the end of the file
3. Restart Apache by running this command: `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod json
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

configure your php.ini

then restart your apache.